# Solving Diophantine Equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

$x$,$y$ are integers such that $~x^{2}+1=y^{x}$.
Find all pairs of $(x,y)$.

I know that it's a diophantine equation but don't have any idea.
Also I can't find anything related to it by search function.

Comment: I am not sure this is a diophantine equation, since diophantine equations are usually polynomials, and $y^x$ is not a polynomial. This is sometimes called an exponential diophantine equation. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation#Exponential_Diophantine_equations .

Comment: Hint: Since $y$ only appears once in the equation, treat $y$ as "some integer" and focus on $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, y = $\sqrt[x]{x^2+1}$.  How many integers of this form are there?  This function has a maximum value (~2.2) and a minimum (~0.4), so you can bound $y \in [1,2]$.  If $y=1$, the equation is $x^2+1=1$, which is trivial.  If $y=2$, the equation is $x^2+1 = 2^x$ and it's easy to show via the derivative that there are no solutions with $x>5$ (RHS too big).  Since the LHS is an integer for all integer $x$ and the RHS is not an integer for $x<0$ you have another bound.  Searching this space is pretty quick...